# Is there a way to reference a kubernetes secret in a Kong plugin yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kubernetes-secrets, kong-plugin

I have a Kong introspection plugin and would like the introspection url to pull the data from a kubernetes secret. Is this possible?

```html
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: oauth2-introspection
  namespace: app
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kong
consumerRef:
plugin: oauth2-introspection
config:
  introspection_url: **<k8-secret>**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kong Ingress Controller allows you to configure plugins using the contents of a Kubernetes secret. The `configFrom` field in the `KongPlugin` resource allows you to set a `secretKeyRef` pointing to a Kubernetes secret.

This only works for a **COMPLETE** configuration. You can not configure individual fields.

This `KongPlugin` definition points to a secret named `rate-limit-redis` that contains a complete configuration for the plugin:

```bash
echo "
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
 name: rate-limiting-example
plugin: rate-limiting
configFrom:
  secretKeyRef:
    name: rate-limit-redis
    key: config
" | kubectl apply -f -
```

The `rate-limit-redis` secret contains a complete configuration as a string:

```bash
echo "
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: rate-limit-redis
stringData:
  config: |
    minute: 10
    policy: redis
    redis_host: redis-master
    redis_password: PASSWORD
type: Opaque
" | kubectl apply -f -
```

KIC will resolve the secrets, build a complete configuration object and send it to Kong Gateway